# Why is "await Publish<T>" hanging / not completing / not finishing

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

The following piece of code has been working for some time and it has suddenly stopped returning:

```
await availableChangedPublishEndpoint
   .Publish<IAvailableStockChanged>(
        AvailableStockCounter.ConvertSkuQtyToAvailableStockChangedEvent(
            newAvailable,
            absMessage.Warehouse)
        );
```

There is nothing clever in `ConvertSkuQtyToAvailableStockChangedEvent` - it just maps one simple class to another.

We added logs before and after this code and it's definitely just stopping at this point. Other systems are publishing fine, other messages are being sent from this application (for e.g. logs are actually sent via RabbitMQ). We have redeployed and we have upgraded to latest MassTransit version. We are seeing that the messages are being published - possibly multiple times, but this `Publish` method never returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We had a broken RabbitMQ node and a clean service restart on one node fixed it.** I appreciate there might be other reasons for this behaviour, but this was our problem.

`systemctl restart rabbitmq-server`

Looking further into RabbitMQ we saw that some of the *empty* queues that were connected to this exchange were not synchronized (see below) and when we tried to synchronize them that wouldn't work.

[image]

We also couldn't delete some of these unsynchronized queues.

We believe an unexpected shutdown of one of the nodes had caused this problem - but it left most queues / exchanges completely OK.

Comment: How do you deal with resetting all bindings on RMQ? We want to move all message types (contracts) but we are afraid all bindings will be corrupt.

Comment: We didn't have to reset any bindings - we did delete a couple of the empty unsynchronised queues that were connected to this exchange as we thought that might solve the problem as MassTransit would recreate when we restart the applications that needed those queues - but one actually refused to delete (it crashed the management interface so hard the tab stopped responding) and that's when we did the node restart.

Comment: @Ozkan if that doesn't answer your question can you ask a more detailed question on SO and link to it?